# Unity 5.5 obsolete particle system code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, updates, deprecated, particle-system

Before 5.5 particle system variables could be accessed via [ParticleSystem](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.html) and were read/write. Now they're accessed via [ParticleSystem.MainModule](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.MainModule.html) and thus a lot of code has become obsolete. The [API Updater](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/APIUpdater.html) has not been able to fix most of the issues. I've read through the new documentation but I can't figure out how the new variable types are supposed to be used. For example in JetParticleEffect.cs this line causes a warning:

```
// set the original properties from the particle system
m_OriginalLifetime = m_System.startLifetime;
```

The warning states: 'ParticleSystem.startLifetime' is obsolete: 'startLifetime property is deprecated. Use main.startLifetime or main.startLifetimeMultiplier instead.'

I've tried the following:

```
m_OriginalLifetime = m_System.main.startLifetime;
// error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve' to 'float'
```

I believe the answer has something to do with the minMaxCurve [constant](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve-constant.html) variables as this compiles:

```
m_OriginalLifetime = m_System.main.startLifetime.constant;
```

But there is almost no explaination in the docs. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Also, where do the new multipliers fit in? I assume where previously you could do this:

```
particle.startSize *= myMultiplier
```

... you should now do this?

```
particle.main.startSizeMultiplier = myMultiplier
```

Comment: m_OriginalLifetime = (float)m_System.main.startLifetime;

Comment: I typed a long answer for this question yesterday. Was about to post it and you deleted it. Too lazy to type it again but this problem reminds me of [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338427/question-deleted-by-op-while-in-the-process-of-posting-answer).

Comment: My apologies, I didn't think the question was well worded and on re-reading it I felt that hadn't done enough of my own research to justify asking the community. I've since read all of the the relevant docs and feel my new question is more precise.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**particle.startLifetime:**

First of all, what Unity did in Unity 5.5 was to add new futures to the `ParticleSystem`. They also exposed some `ParticleSystem` API that was hidden before.

[`ParticleSystem.MainModule.startLifetime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.MainModule-startLifetime.html) is now a type of [`MinMaxCurve`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve.html) instead of float like `ParticleSystem.startLifetime`.

By doing this, you are now given more options such as modifying the `startLifetime` as a curve.

Reading or writing to `ParticleSystem.MainModule.startLifetime` depends on the value of `ParticleSystem.MainModule.startLifetime.mode` which is set through the Editor or via code.

[image]

The default value of `ParticleSystem.MainModule.startLifetime.mode` is ParticleSystemCurveMode.Constant

So your `m_OriginalLifetime = m_System.main.startLifetime.constant;` is fine.

If `startLifetime` is dynamically or randomly changed to another **mode** during run-time, then you will have to do something like this:

```
ParticleSystem m_System = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
ParticleSystem.MainModule main = m_System.main;

ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve minMaxCurve = main.startLifetime;

if (minMaxCurve.mode == ParticleSystemCurveMode.Constant)
{
    m_OriginalLifetime = m_System.main.startLifetime.constant;
}
else if (minMaxCurve.mode == ParticleSystemCurveMode.Curve)
{
    AnimationCurve animCurveLifetime = m_System.main.startLifetime.curve;
}
...
```

---

**particle.startSize:**

The-same thing apply to `particle.startSize`.
The `particle.startSize` property is now `m_System.main.startSize;`

Although you **can't** do `m_System.main.startSize.constant *= myMultiplier;` because your old code was `particle.startSize *= myMultiplier`.

You need to get `m_System.main.startSize`, modify it then assign the modified `m_System.main.startSize` back to `m_System.main.startSize`.

`particle.startSize *= myMultiplier` should be:

```
ParticleSystem m_System = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
ParticleSystem.MainModule main = m_System.main;

ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve minMaxCurve = main.startSize; //Get Size

minMaxCurve.constant *= myMultiplier; //Modify Size
main.startSize = minMaxCurve; //Assign the modified startSize back
```

---

**Then, what are `particle.main.startSizeMultiplier` and `particle.main.startSize` used for?**

This two variables can also be used to change `startLifetime` and `startSize`. It's main advantage is that it is very efficient. It does not not require that you make a copy of `MinMaxCurve` like we did above, in order to change `startSize` or `startSizeMultiplier`.

```
ParticleSystem m_System = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
ParticleSystem.MainModule main = m_System.main;
main.startSizeMultiplier = 5;
```

and

```
ParticleSystem m_System = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
ParticleSystem.MainModule main = m_System.main;
main.startLifetimeMultiplier = 8;
```

Use them if your `ParticleSystem.MainModule.startLifetime.mode` is constant. This will to change the overall lifetime multiplier or the the overall size multiplier efficiently.

---

### **Changing Color and Color Modes**

**Color**:

There is an implicit operator that lets you use:

```
ParticleSystem.MainModule main = trailPartical.main;
main.startColor = Color.red;
```

but `startColor` is not actually type of `Color`. The `startColor` variable is now a type of `ParticleSystem.MinMaxGradient`.

This is how you should be changing the particle `startColor`:

```
//Create Color
ParticleSystem.MinMaxGradient color = new ParticleSystem.MinMaxGradient();
color.mode = ParticleSystemGradientMode.Color;
color.color = Color.red;

//Assign the color to your particle
ParticleSystem.MainModule main = trailPartical.main;
main.startColor = color;
```

---

**Gradient**:

```
public ParticleSystem particleSystem;

void Start()
{
    //Create Gradient key
    GradientColorKey[] gradientColorKey;
    gradientColorKey = new GradientColorKey[3];
    gradientColorKey[0].color = Color.red;
    gradientColorKey[0].time = 0f;
    gradientColorKey[1].color = Color.blue;
    gradientColorKey[1].time = 0.5f;
    gradientColorKey[2].color = Color.green;
    gradientColorKey[2].time = 1f;

    //Create Gradient alpha
    GradientAlphaKey[] gradientAlphaKey;
    gradientAlphaKey = new GradientAlphaKey[3];
    gradientAlphaKey[0].alpha = 1.0f;
    gradientAlphaKey[0].time = 0.0f;
    gradientAlphaKey[1].alpha = 0.5f;
    gradientAlphaKey[1].time = 0.5f;
    gradientAlphaKey[2].alpha = 1f;
    gradientAlphaKey[2].time = 1f;

    //Create Gradient
    Gradient gradient = new Gradient();
    gradient.SetKeys(gradientColorKey, gradientAlphaKey);

    //Create Color from Gradient
    ParticleSystem.MinMaxGradient color = new ParticleSystem.MinMaxGradient();
    color.mode = ParticleSystemGradientMode.Gradient;
    color.gradient = gradient;

    //Assign the color to particle
    ParticleSystem.MainModule main = particleSystem.main;
    main.startColor = color;
}
```

---

**Random Between Two Colors**:

```
//Create Color from Gradient
ParticleSystem.MinMaxGradient color = new ParticleSystem.MinMaxGradient();
color.mode = ParticleSystemGradientMode.TwoColors;
color.colorMin = Color.red;
color.colorMax = Color.green;

//Assign the color to the particle
ParticleSystem.MainModule main = particleSystem.main;
main.startColor = color;
```

---

**Random Between Two Gradients**:

```
public ParticleSystem particleSystem;

void Start()
{

    //Create Gradient key Min
    GradientColorKey[] gradientColorKeyMin;
    gradientColorKeyMin = new GradientColorKey[3];
    gradientColorKeyMin[0].color = Color.red;
    gradientColorKeyMin[0].time = 0f;
    gradientColorKeyMin[1].color = Color.blue;
    gradientColorKeyMin[1].time = 0.5f;
    gradientColorKeyMin[2].color = Color.green;
    gradientColorKeyMin[2].time = 1f;

    //Create Gradient alpha Min
    GradientAlphaKey[] gradientAlphaKeyMin;
    gradientAlphaKeyMin = new GradientAlphaKey[3];
    gradientAlphaKeyMin[0].alpha = 1.0f;
    gradientAlphaKeyMin[0].time = 0.0f;
    gradientAlphaKeyMin[1].alpha = 0.5f;
    gradientAlphaKeyMin[1].time = 0.5f;
    gradientAlphaKeyMin[2].alpha = 1f;
    gradientAlphaKeyMin[2].time = 1f;

    //Create Gradient key Max
    GradientColorKey[] gradientColorKeyMax;
    gradientColorKeyMax = new GradientColorKey[3];
    gradientColorKeyMax[0].color = Color.red;
    gradientColorKeyMax[0].time = 0f;
    gradientColorKeyMax[1].color = Color.blue;
    gradientColorKeyMax[1].time = 0.5f;
    gradientColorKeyMax[2].color = Color.green;
    gradientColorKeyMax[2].time = 1f;

    //Create Gradient alpha Max
    GradientAlphaKey[] gradientAlphaKeyMax;
    gradientAlphaKeyMax = new GradientAlphaKey[3];
    gradientAlphaKeyMax[0].alpha = 1.0f;
    gradientAlphaKeyMax[0].time = 0.0f;
    gradientAlphaKeyMax[1].alpha = 0.5f;
    gradientAlphaKeyMax[1].time = 0.5f;
    gradientAlphaKeyMax[2].alpha = 1f;
    gradientAlphaKeyMax[2].time = 1f;

    //Create Gradient Min
    Gradient gradientMin = new Gradient();
    gradientMin.SetKeys(gradientColorKeyMin, gradientAlphaKeyMin);

    //Create Gradient Max
    Gradient gradientMax = new Gradient();
    gradientMax.SetKeys(gradientColorKeyMax, gradientAlphaKeyMax);


    //Create Color from Gradient
    ParticleSystem.MinMaxGradient color = new ParticleSystem.MinMaxGradient();
    color.mode = ParticleSystemGradientMode.TwoGradients;
    color.gradientMin = gradientMin;
    color.gradientMax = gradientMax;

    //Assign the color to the particle
    ParticleSystem.MainModule main = particleSystem.main;
    main.startColor = color;
}
```

---

**Random Color**:

```
public ParticleSystem particleSystem;

void Start()
{

    //Create Gradient key Min
    GradientColorKey[] gradientColorKeyMin;
    gradientColorKeyMin = new GradientColorKey[3];
    gradientColorKeyMin[0].color = Color.red;
    gradientColorKeyMin[0].time = 0f;
    gradientColorKeyMin[1].color = Color.blue;
    gradientColorKeyMin[1].time = 0.5f;
    gradientColorKeyMin[2].color = Color.green;
    gradientColorKeyMin[2].time = 1f;

    //Create Gradient alpha Min
    GradientAlphaKey[] gradientAlphaKeyMin;
    gradientAlphaKeyMin = new GradientAlphaKey[3];
    gradientAlphaKeyMin[0].alpha = 1.0f;
    gradientAlphaKeyMin[0].time = 0.0f;
    gradientAlphaKeyMin[1].alpha = 0.5f;
    gradientAlphaKeyMin[1].time = 0.5f;
    gradientAlphaKeyMin[2].alpha = 1f;
    gradientAlphaKeyMin[2].time = 1f;

    //Create Gradient key Max
    GradientColorKey[] gradientColorKeyMax;
    gradientColorKeyMax = new GradientColorKey[3];
    gradientColorKeyMax[0].color = Color.red;
    gradientColorKeyMax[0].time = 0f;
    gradientColorKeyMax[1].color = Color.blue;
    gradientColorKeyMax[1].time = 0.5f;
    gradientColorKeyMax[2].color = Color.green;
    gradientColorKeyMax[2].time = 1f;

    //Create Gradient alpha Max
    GradientAlphaKey[] gradientAlphaKeyMax;
    gradientAlphaKeyMax = new GradientAlphaKey[3];
    gradientAlphaKeyMax[0].alpha = 1.0f;
    gradientAlphaKeyMax[0].time = 0.0f;
    gradientAlphaKeyMax[1].alpha = 0.5f;
    gradientAlphaKeyMax[1].time = 0.5f;
    gradientAlphaKeyMax[2].alpha = 1f;
    gradientAlphaKeyMax[2].time = 1f;

    //Create Gradient Min
    Gradient gradientMin = new Gradient();
    gradientMin.SetKeys(gradientColorKeyMin, gradientAlphaKeyMin);

    //Create Gradient Max
    Gradient gradientMax = new Gradient();
    gradientMax.SetKeys(gradientColorKeyMax, gradientAlphaKeyMax);


    //Create Color from Gradient
    ParticleSystem.MinMaxGradient color = new ParticleSystem.MinMaxGradient();
    color.mode = ParticleSystemGradientMode.RandomColor;
    color.gradientMin = gradientMin;
    color.gradientMax = gradientMax;


    //Assign the color to the particle
    ParticleSystem.MainModule main = particleSystem.main;
    main.startColor = color;
}
```