# Get particle gradient color

Tags: unity-game-engine

I see how to ***set*** a particle's color based on a gradient (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41393814/unity-5-5-obsolete-particle-system-code/41403778#41403778) & [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/setting-particle-system-startcolors-value-with-gradient-or-2-values-through-c.437926/)) but I can't find anything on how to ***get*** the color.

I have a particle system with the start color set to random with a gradient. I've tried...

```
Color myColor = myParticleSystem.main.startColor.color
```

... but it always returns black, regardless of the gradient colors.

I don't see anything in the docs or forums about how to actually get the color that was randomly chosen.

Using Unity 2017.3. Thanks.

Comment: I think you **can** get the gradient color with the `ParticleSystem.MinMaxGradient.gradient` property which returns [`Gradient`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gradient.html). Have you tried this?

Comment: I never found a way to get that (or others) properties from `ParticleSystem.MinMaxGradient` from code, AFAIK the class still hasn't getters available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, we can't read the `MinMaxCurve` from scripts, as per here: https://blogs.unity3d.com/2016/04/20/particle-system-modules-faq/ (scroll down to the **Easing the Pain** section).

However, your code returns not a `MinMaxCurve`, but the `Start Color` of type `Color` that you can set via inspector or via script.

For example, if you create a `Particle System` game object in a scene, and you attach to it this simple script:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class ParticlesTest : MonoBehaviour {

    ParticleSystem myParticleSystem;
    public Color myColor;

    private void Awake() {
        myParticleSystem = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();      
    }

    private void Update() {
        myColor = myParticleSystem.main.startColor.color;
    }
}
```

you can see that `myColor` changes when you change the `Start Color` value of the `Particle System` in Play mode.

Comment: "We know that you really ought to be able to read particle system curves from script, regardless of what mode they are in". Doh!